# How determine if my stream is listed on a online radio website?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am trying to develop a web application that will do the following:

> 1. Collect the information like websiteUrl, email address, language,
>      stream format (audio, video).
> 2. Now I have a list of directory names and website url and submission
>      url and their accepted stream format
>      (i.e: Radio, Tv or Both) as well as
>      language (english, spanish, freanch,
>      or all language).
> 3. Now when the user put his information described in 1, and click
>      on proceed button, we will first
>      retrieves the name of the directory
>      and all its information saved in the
>      database according to users input
>      (stream format, language) and then we
>      need to look up if the stream is
>      already promoted to any of the
>      directories retrieved from the DB.

I think we need to do a web request and parse the returned html to see if the stream is there.

Is there anyone who can help in this regard? I am really unknown about this type of issue.
Any help in this regard will be a awesome help for me. By the way I am using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and ExtJs to do this project.

Regards,
Mohin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. It seemed that no body wanted to answer my question. I had to struggle a lot and finally found the solution but I was really in a hurry.